# SwiperJs & flexbox, images not full width, variable tiny gap

Tags: css, flexbox, swiper.js

I have a flexbox row layout, with a vertical navbar and two swipers, where **some** of the images do not take full width, there seems to be a width calculation error.

Manipulating the values given to some layout elements fix this in some of the images, but produce the same problem in other images.

This happens with images that share ratio and even exact size.

Removing the vertical navbar seems to do away with the width calculation error altogether, which leds me to believe flexbox is directly responsible or indirectly provoking swiperJs width miscalculation

Here is a demo with red background to better see the gaps:

https://jsfiddle.net/67o0v35z/8/

html

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-top">
        <div class="info navbar-item"><a href="">info</a></div>
        <div class="shows navbar-item"><a href="">works</a></div>
        <div class="works navbar-item"><a href="">shows</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-bottom">
        <div class="logo navbar-item"><a href="">Patata Patata</a></div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="home-show">
    <div class="home-show-area">
        <!-- Slider main container -->    
        <div class="swiper swiper_left">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img 
                        src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=1"
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img 
                        src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=2" 
                    />
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home-show-area">
        <!-- Slider main container -->    
        <div class="swiper swiper_right">
            <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <!-- Slides -->
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img 
                        src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=3" 
                    />
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <img 
                        src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=4" 
                    />
                </div>     
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100vw
}

.navbar {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 2em;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    margin-right: .4vw;
    min-width: 49px;
    padding: 1em 0;
    width: 2.8vw;
    z-index: 10
}

.navbar,.navbar .navbar-bottom,.navbar .navbar-top {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap
}

.navbar .navbar-top {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: flex-start
}

.navbar .navbar-bottom {
    flex: 2;
    justify-content: flex-end
}

.navbar .navbar-item {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-writing-mode: tb-lr;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr
}


.navbar .navbar-item:not(.garden,.logo) {
    padding-top: 1em
}

.home-show {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 0
}

.home-show-area {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1;
    width: 50%
}

.swiper {
    height: 100%
}

.swiper-slide {
    width: 100%!important
}

.swiper-slide img {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    -o-object-position: center;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%
}
```

js

```
const swiperleft = new Swiper(".swiper_left", {
    // Optional parameters
    // direction: "vertical",
    loop: true,
    effect: "fade",
    fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true,
    },
    allowTouchMove: false,
});



const swiperright = new Swiper(".swiper_right", {
    // Optional parameters
    // direction: "vertical",
    loop: true,
    effect: "fade",
    fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true,
    },
    allowTouchMove: false
});

// Home swiper on hover
swiperleft.on("click", function () {
    swiperleft.slideNext();
});

document.querySelector(".swiper_left").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    swiperleft.slideNext()
});

swiperright.on("click", function () {
    swiperright.slideNext();
});

document.querySelector(".swiper_right").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    swiperright.slideNext()
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
const swiperleft = new Swiper("#swiper_left", {
  loop: true,
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true
  },
  allowTouchMove: false
});

const swiperright = new Swiper("#swiper_right", {
  loop: true,
  effect: "fade",
  fadeEffect: {
    crossFade: true
  },
  allowTouchMove: false
});

// Home swiper on hover
swiperleft.on("click", function () {
  swiperleft.slideNext();
});

swiperleft.el.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  swiperleft.slideNext();
});

swiperright.on("click", function () {
  swiperright.slideNext();
});

swiperright.el.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
  swiperright.slideNext();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
  margin: 0;
}

.side {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #fff;
  float: left;
}

.swiper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrap {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% - 25px);
  float: left;
}

.img {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7.4.1/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="swiper swiper_left" id="swiper_left">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=1)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=3)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="swiper swiper_right" id="swiper_right">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=2)"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=4)"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```